# How to proof this polynomial sum formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

Let f(x) be a polynomial with order m.

Denote $\Delta f(x) = f(x + 1) - f(x)$ the difference, and $\Delta^k f(x) = \Delta^{k-1} f(x+1) - \Delta^{k-1} f(x)$.

Then we have the formula
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) &= \binom{n}{1} f(1)+\binom{n}{2}\Delta f(1) + \binom{n}{3} \Delta^3 f(1)+\dots+ \binom{n}{m+1} \Delta^mf(1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \binom{n}{k} \Delta^{k-1} f(1)
\end{aligned}$$

Does this formula has a name? How to proof it?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See "finite differences" [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Finite-difference_calculus) with a first presentation close to your formula and a second more usual nowadays.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can proof it by the method of undetermined coefficients through the fact that \sum f(k) = \sum_k ( f(1) + \sum_{i < k} \Delta f(i)) .
@JeanMarie